# Why isn't ModRewrite returning my regular expression as expected?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am working on dynamic subdomains for my website, so far the ReWrite code I have come up with is:

```
RewriteRule ^.+\:\/\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.{1}.+\.{1}.+\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$ /app.php?var1='$1'&var2='$2'&var3='$3'&var4='$4'
```

When I test it out in the regex tester at http://regexpal.com this is what I get

my simulated input is: `http://testuser.testdomain.com/test/this/out`

and my return is: `app.php?var1='testuser'&var2=''&var3=''&var4=''`

what I am expecting is: `app.php?var1='testuser'&var2='test'&var3='this'&var4='out'`

you can see what I am working with here: [RegExPal Tool RewriteRule](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93604)

**EDIT:**

I don't quite understand the  RewriteCond, so far I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ app.php?content=$1&id=$2&selector=$3&action=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$ app.php?content=$1&id=$2&selector&$3&action=$4

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+://{1}){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+).{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+.{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+/){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$ $1$3app.php?&content=$4&id=$5&selector=$6&action=$7
```

the first condition is if the subdirectory is not set, which is currently working.
the second condition I am working on still, I don't know how to use the RewriteCond and I can't find documentation that explains it very well.

Comment: Do you intend for the 3 path segments to all be optional?

Comment: Amazingly.. I just solved my own problem. i changed the first two "." characters which match any string into "[a-zA-Z0-9]" patterns which somehow solved the problem. Not sure how, maybe someone has an explanation for that? Could possibly help someone else in the future.

new code is `RewriteRule ^.+\:\/\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$ app.php?var1='testuser'&var2='test'&var3='this'&var4='out'`

Comment: If it works now, it is probably a fluke of overpermissive matching. The protocol https? and domain would never appear in `RewriteRule`. Are you sure you successfully matched `testuser` into var1?

Comment: Only in the regex editor.. so basically this rule I just wrote isn't going to work?

Comment: No, not in RewriteRule. You need additional RewriteCond. So do you want those 3 path vars to be optional or required?

Comment: The reason it didn't work before is that your `.+` parts were matching the rest of the url, because the sections meant to match the paths after the domain are all optional (with `?`).  Might I also point out that your `{1}`s are redundant and can be removed.

Comment: I would like the parameters to be optional and I will also have another RewriteRule in the case that the subdomain is omitted, I do have a RewriteCond. code is 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. would I need to modify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to match too much in `RewriteRule`, which itself only receives the *path* `test/this/out`, but not the protocol or host.  To capture the subdomain from the host, you must first match `%{HTTP_HOST}` into the `%1` variable with `RewriteCond`, then match the segments of the path in `RewriteRule`.

Note, I'm using the expression `(:?([^.]+)\.)?`to capture only the part before the dot as subdomain. The `(:?)` on the outer part ensures the dot itself is not captured `\.` in `%1`.

### UPDATED and rewritten as one rule:

After some experimentation, I worked out how to do this in one very complex expression. It uses the same `RewriteCond` matching pattern to grab the subdomain into `%1`, but replaces the path segments with an expression like `(?:([^/]+)(?:/|$))?`

This breaks down as:

- `^` Start of the string received by RewriteRule (the path)
- `(?:` Don't capture a variable for the whole structure
- `([^/]+)` Do capture everything up to the next `/` (but not including it)
- `(?:` Don't capture what comes next...
- `/|$` ... which may be either a slash or the end of the string `$`
- `)` Close that slash or end matching group
- `)` Close the outer group for the whole structure
- `?` And make the entire thing optional

The entire thing above would match the first path segment (`test` in your example `/test/this/out`). Then it is repeated two more times to capture the other two variables.

All together with the `RewriteCond` condition and subdomain match, it looks like;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Added condition for negative match on existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Case-insensitive host match captures the subdomain into %1
# Using [^.]+ to match everything up to the first dot
# using a non-capturing outer group so the dot isn't grabbed
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:([^.]+)\.)?test\.com [NC]
# Match each segment optionally into $1,$2,$3
RewriteRule ^(?:([^/]+)(?:/|$))?(?:([^/]+)(?:/|$))?(?:([^/]+)(?:/|$))? index.php?subdomain='%1'&var2='$1'&var3='$2'&var4='$3' [L]
```

If you may have additional query string parameters that need to be appended, add the `[QSA]` flag, as in `[L,QSA]` to the end of each of these.

[Full documentation on `RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)...

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the way that RewriteCond works, possibly the variables are confusing me. Do consecutive rules concatenate together?

Comment: The RewriteCond works by matching (optionally) and capturing the subdomain, but RewriteCond captures into `%` vars rather than `$`. So it matches `%{HTTP_HOST}` (the full domain) and in the `RewriteRule` part, `%1` is used to pass to var1. But `RewriteRule` itself captures $1, $2, $3 etc, so var2 must use `$1`.

Comment: The `RewriteCond` occur in pairs, and you must reissue the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` for _each_ RewriteRule it may apply to (same with the host matching one). So what I have above in its entirety is what you need to add.  The repeating of those conditions is intended and necessary.

Comment: In your edited example, you still have in `RewriteRule` patterns intended to match `http://subdomain.example.com`, but that string will never be passed to `RewriteRule`. It must be preprocessed by RewriteCond and HTTP_HOST. The only string available to match by `RewriteRule` is `test/this/out`.

Comment: @MichaelO'Neal After thinking on it (a lot), I came up with a regex pattern capable of matching all of the optional path segments in one go. Coupled with the RewriteCond to read the subdomain, I tested this out and can get it to return any number of optional path segments and the subdomain. It should work for you exactly as is (substituting the desired variable names, and correct domain name)

Comment: I like it, it's similar to the one I have working, the '?' Operator really comes in handy to keep my .htaccess clean. I really appreciate all the thought you put into this man, you have no idea how much your help means to me.